# How can we make the minutes value starts from zero after seconds reached to 60?

Tags: javascript, time

I am working on project which need to show some delay time in the format of "hh:mm:ss". When the seconds value reached to 60(means minutes value is 1), then the seconds value again starts from zero. But, when the minutes value reached to 60(means hours value is 1), then the minutes is showing the conitnuous value(61,62,63.....). I need to show the minutes value starts from zero when the hours value is greater than zero. How can I acheive this? Please help me and thanks in advance. Below the code which I have written.

```js
var timer = 0;
setInterval(function () {
         var hours = parseInt(timer / 3600, 10);
         var minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
         var seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
         hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
         minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
         seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
         $scope.delay = $scope.delayTime.label + ": " + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
         if (++timer < 0) {
            $scope.delayTime = false;
         }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: The code snippet currently fails, with "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: timer is not defined".

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Done with edit part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the minutes already contained in the hours to properly calculate the minutes:

```
var hours = parseInt(timer / 3600, 10);
var minutes = parseInt(timer / 60 - hours * 60, 10);
var seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried modulo? Like

- `59 % 60` -> 59
- `60 % 60` -> 0
- `61 % 60` -> 1
- `62 % 60` -> 2
- ...

Just add `minutes = minutes % 60`.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted but It's working. thanks.

Comment: I originally downvoted this because you explained how modulo works (although the OP knows) and failed to address the actual problem. I removed my downvote because of the clarifying edit.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will consider this next time!

Answer (score 2):

Just change your calc on minutes to `(timer / 60) % 60`:

```js
var timer = 3600 - 5;
setInterval(function () {
  var hours = parseInt(timer / 3600, 10);
  var minutes = parseInt((timer / 60) % 60, 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
  hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  //$scope.delay = $scope.delayTime.label + ": " + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  console.log('hours ' + hours + ' minutes ' + minutes + ' seconds ' + seconds);
  if (++timer < 0) {
    //$scope.delayTime = false;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your `minutes` variable contains your whole time in minutes (containing hours):

```
var minutes = parseInt((timer / 60) % 60, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I want to add to rasmeister's answer:

Since many browsers (especially mobile browsers) pause javascript when the browser tab is inactive, I recommend you to use `Date` objects:

```js
var start = +new Date(); // casting Date to number results in timestamp
setInterval(function () {
  // get elapsed time in seconds
  var timer = Math.round((+new Date() - start) / 1000);
  var hours = parseInt(timer / 3600, 10);
  var minutes = parseInt((timer / 60) % 60, 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
  hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  //$scope.delay = $scope.delayTime.label + ": " + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  console.log('hours ' + hours + ' minutes ' + minutes + ' seconds ' + seconds);
  if (timer < 0) {
    //$scope.delayTime = false;
  }
}, 1000);
```